# SCNNode not in SCNView hierarchy, still showing & getting touches & physics

Tags: ios, scenekit

This is an apparent SceneKit bug that took me a while to figure out, and I couldn't find any solutions online.

After an SCNNode removeFromParentNode(), removing it from an SCNView's scene.rootNode hierarchy (I checked it to verify it wasn't hiding somewhere) SceneKit was still rendering it, doing physics contact with it (with a nil SCNPhysicsContact.nodeB), and returning it in UIGestureRecognizer hit test results. No mutation-while-enumerating was going on, but the node hierarchy had clearly got itself into an inconsistent state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It only happened when the node was removed straight after being created (because it was out of range). Adding a short delay to the removal fixed it:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.userInteractive).asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
    emojiNode.removeFromParentNode()
}
```

I'm guessing the SCNView stores the nodes it works with independently to the nodes in it's rootNode hierarchy, probably so it can organize them in a way that's faster to work with, and updates it's separate list when they're added/removed from the real one. Probably some edge case caused by something unusual I'm doing with physics, text nodes or whatever coupled with removing nodes so quickly after it was added probably made the separate list inconsistent with the nodes in the actual node hierarchy.